# Android AudioRecord Overrun user: the filesize of recorded audio is only 44 bytes

Tags: java, android, audio

I am using the extAudioRecorder class (wrapper for AudioRecord) found here to record a .wav file: http://i-liger.com/article/android-wav-audio-recording

I am finding that when I record, my file size is only 44 bytes for some reason, and I'm seeing this message in the log:

`Overrun user: 14ac, server: 3e04, flowControlFlag 1`

This is pretty cryptic to me. I have no idea why it wouldn't be recording the audio properly.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: So you're calling `getInstanse(false)` to get a recorder for uncompressed audio? What if you do compressed recording instead - does that have the same problem?

Comment: Alright, so it works now! But the audio sample I save is of really shitty / noisy quality. Oh well, better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: @YoungMoney -- How did you solve this... I am also getting the same 44 bytes error.